# How to convert data in command object to DateTime?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

```
DateTime DT1;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select DateReceivedProviderInvoice from ProviderInvoices");
```

now how to assing the result of the query to DateTime variable DT1?!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.90).ASPX) Method if you want to get a single value from a column.

> `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`: Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

```
DT1 = Convert.ToDateTime(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```